# BibTex no numbering

Tags: biblatex, overleaf

I am using a template for my thesis which I found on overleaf but I am having trouble getting the bibliography correctly formatted.

In my main.tex, there is a section to include whatever is in the backmatter/bibliography folder

```
% BIBLIOGRAPHY WITH BIBTEX %
\include{backmatter/bibliography}
```

The folder itself contains a bibliography.tex file with the following in it:

```
%*******************************************************
% Bibliography
%*******************************************************
\cleardoublepage
\phantomsection
\addcontentsline{toc}{part}{References}
\printbibliography[title=References]
\nocite{*}
\vspace{2.5cm}
```

The packages folder containing all the packages for the entire document contains these lines for the bibliography (I added \bibliographystyle{plain} in hopes that it would convert it to [1] but it did not):

```
 % To enable the bibliography
    \usepackage[refsection=part,citestyle=harvard,style=authoryear,natbib=true,backend=biber]{biblatex}
    \bibliographystyle{plain}
    \bibliography{bibliography}
```

Currently, my citations and in-line citations are formatted this way:

```
%  ===== MY IN-LINE CITATION ====

(Stats, 2020)

%  ===== Citation in References page ====

Internet World (2020). Most common languages used on the internet as of January
2020, by share of internet users. url: https://www.statista.com/statistics/262946/
share-of-the-most-common-languages-on-the-internet/ (visited on 10/08/2022)

%  ===== MY CITATION in bibliography.bib ====
@online{Statista,
    title = {Most common languages used on the internet as of January 2020, by share of internet users},
    author ={Internet World Stats},
    year= {2020},
    url={https://www.statista.com/statistics/262946/share-of-the-most-common-languages-on-the-internet/},
    urldate = {2022-10-08}
}
```

I would like to change it so that my in-line citation changes from (Stats, 2020) to [1] and for the citations in my Reference page to be preceded by identical numbering like this:

```
[1] Internet World (2020). Most common languages used on the internet as of January
    2020, by share of internet users. url: https://www.statista.co
[2] NEXT REFERENCE
```

Comment: You seem to be using `citestyle=harvard,style=authoryear`  on `biblatex` and want a numerical-sequential style, whose references are formatted such as harvard style. You may check [this link](https://pt.overleaf.com/learn/latex/Biblatex_citation_styles) about how to edit biblatex styles, you're proably looking for option `numeric-comp`. Please, also read about [MWE](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-working-example-mwe-what-is-that)s. Adding images of your results is better than typing them.11

Comment: The command `\bibliographystyle` is not compatible with the `biblatex` package. And you should replace `\bibliography{bibliography}` with `\addbibresource{bibliography.bib}`. Apropos `biblatex` -- the options `citestyle=harvard` and `style=authoryear` produce authoryear-style citation call-outs instead of numeric-style citation call-outs.

Comment: Note that `citestyle=harvard,style=authoryear,` is equivalent to `style=authoryear,`. And that there is no such thing as `...style=harvard,` (at least on CTAN or indeed anywhere else I looked on the web). That makes me think that your template is fairly low-quality in the `biblatex` department.